# Função está zerando último valor do vetor

Tags: c, array, declaração-de-variável

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


/**
2. Faça um programa que, a partir de um vetor de 12 posições, crie funções para: 

A. Digitar valores no vetor; 
B. Imprimir o valor somatório de seus itens; 
C. Imprimir a média dos valores fornecidos;
D. Substituir por 0 todos os números negativos; 
E. Substituir por 0 todos os números repetidos (maiores que 0). 
**/

float SomarVetor(float vet[]){
  float soma=0;
  for(int i=0; i < 12; i++){
    soma += vet[i]; //Somar valores do vetor
  }
  return soma; //Irá retornar a soma total
}


float media(float vet[]){
  float media =0;
  for(int i=0; i < 12; i++){
    media += vet[i]; //Soma os valores
  }
  return media/12;
}


float negativos(float vet[]){
  for(int i=0; i < 12; i++){
    if(vet[i] < 0){
      vet[i] = 0.0; //Substituir valores negativos por 0
    }
  }
}


float repetidos(float vet[]){

  for(int i=0; i < 12; i++){
    for(int j=0; j < 12; j++){
      if(vet[i] == vet[j+1]){
        vet[i] = 0.00;
        j++;
      }else{
        for(int k=11; k > 0; k--){
          if(vet[i] == vet[k]){
            vet[i] = 0.00;
            k--;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


main(){

  float vet[11];// Vetor de 12 posicoes
  int i; 

  for(i=0; i < 12; i++){//Preenchimento do vetor 
    printf("Digite o %d do vetor: ", i);
    scanf("%f", &vet[i]);
  }


  //Respostas
  printf("Soma dos itens do vetor é %.2f\n", SomarVetor(vet));
  printf("Media: %.2f\n", media(vet));
  negativos(vet);
  //repetidos(vet);

  for(i=0; i < 12; i++){
    printf("%.2f | ", vet[i]);
  }
}
```

Por que a função `negativos()` está fazendo o a ultima posição do vetor ficar como zero também? Sendo que a condição para zerar é que seja número negativo?

Comment: `float vet[11];// Vetor de 12 posicoes` não, tem 11 posições, por isso que eu falo que não se deve comentar código querendo dizer o que ele faz, porque ele pode dizer uma coisa e o código fazer outra, é só confusão.

Comment: Mas não conta o zero?

Comment: Começa do 0, ali você tem que colocar a quantidade de elementos, não o último deles.

Comment: Qdo eu vejo isso eu costumo ter vontade de chorar: `
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

Comment: Nossa que mancada, resolvido

Comment: Ata porque é só uma linha né, não precisa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A declaração de um *array* deve constar a quantidade de elementos que se espera usar dele. Como os elementos começam em 0, o último será o tamanho menos um. Mas a quantidade de elementos é a quantidade de elementos, não tem deslocamento, conta normalmente.

Só cuidado porque em C não há muita proteção, se tentar acessar fora desta faixa, ele deixa e corrompe a memória.

Comment: O que tu chama de corromper memória? Irá ter valores "lixos" armazenados em locais não definidos?